# npm install module failed due to ssl problem

Tags: ssl, npm, npm-install

I am on windows 10 with node v21.2.0 and npm  v10.2.3.
I would like to install a node module like 'npm install express' and the following message comes back

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: write EPROTO 4C130000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

The path referenced above is from a older wampserver installation which I already deinstalled
c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
But maybe this path remains somewhere on the system.
So the question is: What is going wrong here ?. How can get rid of the path ?. How is npm accessing the ssl routines and where it is stored ?.

Oh and yes I searched the windows registry for 'c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl' without result.

I deinstalled wampserver
I uninstalled npm via winget and installed latest npm via winget again.
I can npm install express on another windows 10 in the same network.
I am behind a proxy but the proxy settings are the same and winget in general works behind it.
I tested in windows terminal, powershell and windows cmd.